# Odoo 10 - Problems with require() function in JS

Tags: javascript, odoo-website

I have create a custom module to display calendar in Website

My In JS can't invoke the require().

My Code

**website_calendar_block.js**

```
odoo.define('website_calendar_block', function(require) {    "use strict";
 var website = require('website.website');

alert(website);

});
```

**website_calendar_templates.xml**

```
<template id="website_calendar_assets_frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Calendar block assets">

<xpath expr="/t" position="inside">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/website_calendar/static/src/js/website_calendar_block.js"></script>

</xpath> </template>

<div class="calendar"> <span class="fa fa-2x fa-calendar"/></div>
```

MY problem is when loading website page im getting alert Undefined in alert(website);

can anyone please help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is website.assets_fronted :

```
<template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="web.assets_frontend" name="Website Frontend Assets">
<xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="/website/static/src/less/website.ui.less"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="/website/static/src/less/website.ui.components.less"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="/website/static/src/less/website.wrapwrap.less"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="/website/static/src/less/website.snippets.less"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/website/static/src/less/website.zoomodoo.less"/>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/website/static/src/js/website.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/website/static/src/js/website.share.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/website/static/src/js/website.snippets.animation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/website/static/src/js/website.zoomodoo.js"></script>
</xpath>
</template>
```

How do you find the t element with your xpath ?
It must have found something else if it is not throwing an error, so it is possible that your Javascript code is called before the website assets are even loaded.

Why not use `<xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">` like in website.assets_frontend ?